# How to format specflow .feature file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, specflow

This may sound silly but Is there a way format specflow .feature file? in .cs file I can do ctrl+E ctrl+D  I have to format my tables manually which is a hideous work.

I am not sure if this is related to my VS2013 setting but the Given,And and Then steps won't collapse and expand at all.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is still looking for an answer, I haven't found any extensions in VS that allows to do that.

But I found a chrome app that does, but you need to paste your whole feature file there though.

If that works for you here is the app, it's called Tidy Gherkin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tidy-gherkin/nobemmencanophcnicjhfhnjiimegjeo

Answer (score 5):

If the VS extension for SpecFlow is installed correctly, the VS editor should offer the following support to edit feature files:

- Scenarios (G/W/T) can be collapsed to scenario title Syntax coloring for G/W/T, step parameters and bound/unbound steps
- Intelli-sense for Gherkin keywords and defined steps
- Navigation between scenario lines and step definitions
- Generation of skeleton step definitions from scenarios/feature files
- Table formatting: when you type a closing pipe for a column, all columns above and right to the closed column will be re-aligned

Does any of these features work for you? If not, you might yet need to install the SpecFlow VS extension from VS Gallery (note that this is something different than the SpecFlow NuGet package for the project).

Comment: all of the above works except for the first one. I already have the extension installed I also got the error when i try to install to check if I have it or not. But I got a message saying I already have extension in VS2013

Comment: Get the 2019 version here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TechTalkSpecFlowTeam.SpecFlowForVisualStudio

Answer (score 4):

Shortcut keys to format specflow table is Shift+|(press shift and Pipe Symbol). 
Place the cursor at the end of the table on Specflow, so it does format the respective table on key press of "shift And |(Pipe,Or Symbol).

Hope you will find it helpful.